# ADT specification

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, adt

Does any one know any tutorial where I can go to fully understand the syntax of this notation?

```
/* value definition */
abstract typedef <int, int> RATIONAL;
condition RATIONAL[1] != 0;

/* Operator definitions */

abstract equal( a, b )                        /* written a == b */
RATIONAL a, b;
postcondition equal == ( a[0] * b[1] == b[0] * a[1] )

abstract RATIONAL makerational( a, b )      /*  written [a, b] */
int a, b;
precondition b != 0;
postcondition makerational[0] * b == a * makerational[1]

abstract RATIONAL add( a, b )            /* written a + b */
RATIONAL a, b;
postcondition add == [ a[0] * b[1] + b[0] * a[1], a[1] * b[1] ]

abstract RATIONAL mult( a, b )
RATIONAL a, b;
postcondition mult == [ a[0] * b[0], a[1] * b[1] ]
```

Comment: What language is that?  It's not either of the two you've labeled it as.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what a **rational number** is, namely one integer divided by another, then it's not difficult to figure out that notation.

I have never seen it before, but from the properties of rational numbers (fractions) it's clear that the square brackets indexing is for a representation as a vector of two integers.

Then, in ordinary math notation,

```
upper( rational( a, b ) ) = a
lower( rational( a, b ) ) = b

equal( r1, r2 ) = (upper(r1)*lower(r2) eq upper(r2)*lower(r1) )
add( r1, r2 ) = rational(upper(r1)*lower(r2)+upper(r2)*lower(r1), lower(r1)*lower(r2))
mul( r1, r2 ) = rational(upper(r1)*upper(r2), lower(r1)*lower(r2))
```

Cheers & hth,

Answer (score -1):

makerational looks really recursive, doesn't it!
The book "Data Structures Using C and C++, by Yedidyah Langsam, Moshe J. Augenstein, and Aaron M. Tenenbaum, second edition" has a good discussion. It initially shows

postcondition makerational[0] == a;
              makerational[1] == b;

then it discusses the fact that 1/2 and 2/4 should be considered equal, and revises the definition. I think it could be read something like :
The [0] element of the resulting RATIONAL times b must equal the [1] element of the resulting RATIONAL times a